Can i be an extremely famous rapper in Jannah?
Its always been one of my biggest dreams to be a world famous rapper. But I never went for it because its haram. Can I have it in Jannah instead?

Famous to whom? Think! Why would fame add anything to what you could have in Jannah anyway?

What do you mean?

As far as i know , In Sha Allah when we enter Jannah we would not even about these Worldy affairs like becoming a rapper or becoming a doctor , IT WOULD ALL BE GONE AKHI
